# No access with notepadqq on /opt/lampp/htdocs

Tags: xampp, notepadqq

I'm new to Ubuntu and already have my first problem I just cant understand.
I've set `chmod 777` on `/opt/lampp/htdocs` (also set me as owner).
When I open `index.php`, which is located in the `htdocs` directory via `gedit`, it works perfect. But when I try to open that file with `notepadqq`, I don't see its content and I'm also unable to save that file there.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you alot N0rbert :)